# DevExpress Grid Control datasource

Tags: devexpress, datasource, gridcontrol

i'm using grid control in DevExpress reports when i set data source dynamically to my grid control its not showing a output, anyone please help me to get.

this is my code

```
        DataTable dtJobOrder = new DataTable();
        string DTQuery = @"Select Product from JobOrder";

        dtJobOrder = Generic.GetDataTable(DTQuery);
        grdspare.DataSource = dtJobOrder;
```

Comment: Are you sure your dtJobOrder contains rows ?

Comment: you can check `dtJobOrder.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already found a way. 
You can achieve this by calling PopulateColumns method on grid view.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dynamically set the data source to gridview then you have to set AutoGeneratedColumns to true.

```
AutoGeneratedColumns = true
```